# appcelerator iOS application error with geolocation module

Tags: ios, geolocation, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

We are developing app for `iOS` and `Android` and we are using `Ti.Gelocation` to `getCurrentPosition` and then set the `Region` of the `MapView` of `ti.map` module.

The app is already on marketplace and downloaded, so we are developing an important upgrade with this new feature. We dont't have problem with `Android` platform, but with `iOS` version of the app we get a several error invoking `Ti.Geolocation` module

The error on `iOS 9.x` on `iPad` and `iPhone` (we have no test on iPod) is:

> -[__NSCFString containsObject:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1463d500 at GeoView.js (line xxxx)

This error happens with the project with `it.vocami.vocamiapp app-id`, in the test project (`ap-id=it.vocami.vocamitest`) that we use for research and test of new features, no error happens and all run good. When we add at every level of our code (in the first row too), for example, `Ti.Geolocation.locationServiceEnabled`, in the main vocamiapp project, we get the error.

We have tried all we could think but at the end, if we change the app-id, the code runs otherwise we get the error. We cannot change the app-id because we need to update our published app.

We are developing with AppceleratorStudio version 4.5.0.021602170281 and Ti SDK ver 5.2.0GA on Mac OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Very odd to think changing the app ID would affect the code. What is the exact code on that line the error talks about?

Comment: Yes we think this too, but if we copy the project folder in a new project without tiapp.xml that contains only the minimal change (id, name  and guid) we don't get the error. Maybe the project is an 1 year old project created with titanium studio and 3.x sdk? Any use of "Ti.Geolocation" gives us the error. The first use of it is "Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermission(Ti.Geolocation.AUTORIZATION_ALWAYS, function (e) { ... });"

Comment: That might be because the name of the constant is `Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS` (notice the `H`)

Answer (score 0):

I just recently was "hit" by the fact that when I made my app ready for Google Play I use a specific key/user to sign it with. That behaves differently from just running it locally on the phone.

I had to make sure that I had registered two certificates with Google's API in the developer console. It didn't give me exactly the message that you show - but wouldn't show the map with a location. And the way I read the location prior to showing it on the map led me in the wrong direction looking at permissions on Android first :-)

/John

Comment: Yes, that you remeber us, is to use the "ti.map" module on android platform and we did all that, infact we have no problem with android version of the app.